# Camel Transaction Error

Tags: error-handling, transactions, apache-camel

As mentioned in below article
http://camel.apache.org/transactionerrorhandler.html
Im trying to use the transactionErrorHandler like below

```
errorHandler(transactionErrorHandler().maximumRedeliveries(6));
```

it says transactionErrorHandler() is undefined. Do i need to include or extend some class instead of RouteBuilder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transactionErrorHandler() exists in SpringRouteBuilder which extends RouteBuilder